# Change Spring profile from Consul configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, spring-profiles, spring-cloud-consul

Migrating an SpringApplication I find that there are profiles used to run in different modes.  Anytime there may be different instances with different profiles running in production at the same time.

I want to be able to change those Spring profiles from Consul. But Consul seems to work the other way arround. Profiles change properties.

How can I change the profile from Consul?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the profile from consul, but your service needs to restart to work with new profile.